# How to debug nativescript throwing "NativeScript caught signal 11." error?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I have created a plugin for nativescript ios which was working fine until recently I updated the pod version.
Now, when I run the plugin, I get this error:
   NativeScript caught signal 11.

I have already double checked the typings and there was no typo or parameter mismatch there.

```
NativeScript caught signal 11.
Native Stack:
1   0x104c6cf70 sig_handler(int)
2   0x1f46f99dc <redacted>
3   0x104c5e768 NativeScript::ObjCMethodWrapper::postInvocation(NativeScript::FFICall*, JSC::ExecState*, NativeScript::FFICall::Invocation&)
4   0x104bf500c NativeScript::FunctionWrapper::call(JSC::ExecState*)
5   0x1056d7a58 llint_entry
6   0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
7   0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
8   0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
9   0x1056d7318 llint_entry
10  0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
11  0x1056d7318 llint_entry
12  0x1056d6e4c llint_entry
13  0x1056d6e4c llint_entry
14  0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
15  0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
16  0x1056d6e4c llint_entry
17  0x1056d6eb4 llint_entry
18  0x1056cf91c vmEntryToJavaScript
19  0x1054ce84c JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&)
20  0x104c61238 NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::callFunction(JSC::JSValue const&, JSC::ArgList const&, void*)
21  0x104c60d58 NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback::ffiClosureCallback(void*, void**, void*)
22  0x104c6142c NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*)
23  0x1056d9794 ffi_closure_SYSV_inner
24  0x1056dc1b4 .Ldo_closure
25  0x2213f1040 <redacted>
26  0x220e9a1c8 <redacted>
27  0x220e9a4e8 <redacted>
28  0x220e99554 <redacted>
29  0x221428304 <redacted>
30  0x22142952c <redacted>
31  0x22140959c <redacted>
JS Stack:
1   initWithConfiguration@[native code]
2   start@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-nsjumioplugin/nsjumioplugin.js:22:97
3   onSelectSingleTap@file:///app/app/pages/user/info/identification/identification.component.js:109:33
4   @:34:44
5   callWithDebugContext@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:24198:34
6   dispatchEvent@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20577:40
7   @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js:238:31
8   onInvoke@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17344:43
9   run@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:138:49
10  zonedCallback@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js:237:27
11  notify@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:31
12  _emit@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:127:24
13  tap@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/button/button.js:216:24
14  UIApplicationMai<\M-b\M^@\M-&>
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7393 It might be something related to `nativescript-plugin-firebase`, you could try to update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the signal 11 error is a general error that can be caused by many things that others mentioned in comments.

In my case, my IP was blocked by OneSignal's servers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have used this command to run the app

```
tns run ios --bundle --no-hmr --clean --log trace
```

Or maybe IP blocked on [OneSignal's servers](https://onesignal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: 
I've got `NativeScript caught signal 11` while using RadSideDrawer. 
I've tried to use `drawerContentSize="drawerSize"` instead of correct `[drawerContentSize]="drawerSize"` (since drawerSize is a getter in my ts file)

So generally I may assume that it may happen if you forget square brackets (sometimes)

Comment: Thank you. Actually in my case the issue was my IP was blocked by OneSignal's servers. I forgot to update this question.

Comment: I think in my case its RadDataForm. Because I get this error only in pages with RadDataForm.